# What was this 1970s scale drawing device called?

Tags: terminology, tools, history

Back in the 1970s we used to have a projector-type device to make scale drawings of archaeological artefacts. It was a big beast with a glass drawing platform under a hood and handles on the front to adjust scale and focus. What was this 1970s scale drawing device called?

Comment: When I was sent down to the equipment closet to collect A/V equipment in elementary school in the 70s, this was called an "opaque projector" on the sign-out sheet. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_projector ).

Answer (score 3):

Preface: I've *never* used one of these projectors in my *professional career*. The art department when I was in college had one for students to use. So, I *have* used one but my exposure to them is limited a great deal, meaning one. `:)` By the time I started landing jobs which would make use of these projectors, technology had advanced enough (i.e. scanning) and that made such projectors pretty much obsolete.

---

They are simply "copy projectors", "Art Projectors", "Illustration Projectors", etc.

The one we had in college was an "**Artograph**" model. And that's pretty much what *everyone* called them all the time - "artographs" - regardless of the *actual* brand or model.

However, [**Artograph**](https://www.artograph.com/) is merely one *brand name* - Similar to how many people call all tissue "Kleenex", even though Kleenex is merely *one brand* of tissue.

Now days they are small projectors which can work with phones or other electronic photo devices.

But back pre-90s they were much larger and resembled traditional overhead projectors much more closely - merely designed to project vertically rather than horizontally:

[image]

You can read some history of the Artograph brand [here](https://www.artograph.com/history/).

There were many various models and brands of these projectors - some designed to simply handle projections of flat images and others designed to project objects. Some had hoods, some didn't, or the hood was optional depending on the range of projection (how tall it could go)

Comment: That looks more like one of those hairdryers they used to have in beauty salons in the fifties than an overhead projector.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific thing, but probably an overhead projector will do:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_projector

Comment: Thanks for the info but the device I remember had a shelf arrangement for the object underneath the drawing glass. Presumably the image was reflected somehow on the underside of the drawing surface. I can see how the basic principle of the of the artgraph might be the same but on the device I use you could trace the image without throwing shadow onto the drawing surface.

Answer (score 0):

It was called a Viewer. It is in the "Commercial Art Projectors" section of an elderly catalogue.

There were several models made by the Goodkin Company. I'm holding the catalog in my hand.

There was the Model A viewer $695. The adjustable lights were an additional $895.
The 5B viewer was the cheapest at $495. Lights for it were an additional $645.
The Swivel-Top Goodkin was $695.

The text from the catalog is [here](https://archive.org/stream/TNM_Goodkin_-_commercial_art_projectors_and_acces_20170629_0271/TNM_Goodkin_-_commercial_art_projectors_and_acces_20170629_0271_djvu.txt)

[image: I'll try to add some of the illustrations when I can.]

Answer (score 0):

I have an old Goodkin Projector similar to the ones pictured in your catalogue. Pretty incredible machine. Don't think there's many around anymore unfortunately.[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Old American Optics Opaque Projector]

I know this thread is old, but I ran across it while trying to describe this same type projector to a friend. The ones I remember from school were blue, not tan. I found the picture on an electronic sales site called Olde Goode Things. It is the closest to what I remember. I think it is also what the OP was describing. Ours were mounted on the same type rolling cart that TV and VCRs were, so it seemed like this massive contraption back then.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we used to call it the Luci which comes from the original Lucida Camera device.

Answer (score 0):

That is an ArtoGraph DB300 art projector. You tape a photo or sketch to a flip up board inside and it projects the image down to the table surface, onto a piece of paper, illustration board or canvas.

Illustrators use this to transfer images to a paper surface and then finish it at the drawing table with oil, watercolor, etc.

Due to the fast turnaround required in the field of commercial illustration, such devices are required. No one has time to sit and sketch out images by looking at a photo. Illustrators going back decades have used photographs for reference. Norman Rockwell used them exclusively. It's not like he had 10 people pose in a group for hours on end to paint them!

Contrary to opinions cited here, it is by no means obsolete. You can't really get a 12 x 18 piece of illustration board into a printer. And if you want REAL artwork, like actual paint on paper or canvas, and not computer generated stuff, you would use a device like this.

I have one, which I bought in the late 80s and I still use it to this day.
I also have a digital ArtoGraph projector that projects jpeg images from a thumb drive onto paper or canvas. That is the modern equivalent.